# Parsing XML child tags with same name using ElementTree

Tags: xml, csv, xml-parsing, elementtree, python-2.6

I am trying to parse an XML file (in Python which is new for me) with below structure:

```
<xml>
<document>
<fit>
<grp> some tags </grp>
<prp> 
<p> <id> 1674 </id> </p>
<drp> 
<name> Joe </name>
<post> 
<company> abc </company>
<company> Ltd. </company>
</post>
</drp>
</prp>
</fit>
</document>
<document>
.
.
.
</xml>
```

To extract information like id, name, company and then writing them to csv, I tried following code:

```
tree = ET.parse(file)
root=tree.getroot()
with open(csvfile, 'a') as f:
    writer=csvDictWriter(f, ['ID', 'NAME', 'NCOMP'], delimiter=', ')
    writer.writeheader()
    result = {}
    for child in root.findall('./fit'):
        result['ID'] = ( "" .join(child.find('p').find('id').text))
        result['NAME'] = ( "" .join(child.find('drp').find('name'))
        result['NCOMP'] = ( "" .join(child.find('drp').find('post').find('company')
        writer.write(result)
```

However, for the company name, I am only getting the first tag's contents,then I tried using for loop and appending to a list like this:

```
Com = []
for each in child.find('drp').find('post'):
    coms = each.find('company')
    Com = Com.append[coms]
    result['NCOMP'] = Com
```

Desired Output:

```
ID.      NAME.     NCOMP
1674.    Joe.      abc Ltd.
```

How can I change the code so that it incorporates the value of both tags?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Well crafted first question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines; it uses lxml to collect the data via xpath, and pandas to store it in a dataframe:

```
data = """
<xml>
   <document>
      <fit>
         <grp>some tags</grp>
         <prp>
            <p>
               <id>1674</id>
            </p>
            <drp>
               <name>Joe</name>
               <post>
                  <company>abc</company>
                  <company>Ltd.</company>
               </post>
            </drp>
         </prp>
      </fit>
   </document>
</xml>
"""

from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

columns = ["ID", "NAME", "NCOMP"]
rows = []

doc = etree.XML(data)

targets = doc.xpath('//prp')
for target in targets:
    row = []
    id = target.xpath('./p/id/text()')[0]
    name = target.xpath('./drp/name/text()')[0]
    ncomp = target.xpath('./drp//post//company/text()')
    row.extend([id,name,' '.join(ncomp)])    
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    ID     NAME     NCOMP
0   1674    Joe     abc Ltd.
```

Edit - ET version.

first:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

then, starting with `doc` replace with:

```
doc = ET.fromstring(data)
et_targets = doc.findall('.//prp')
for target in et_targets:
    row = []
    id = target.findall('./p/id')[0]
    name = target.findall('./drp/name')[0]
    ncomp = target.findall('./drp//post//company')[0]
    row.extend([id.text,name.text,' '.join(ncomp.text)])    
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output should be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to implement the same using Element Tree?

Comment: @python6 Probably; but xpath support in ET is very limited, so I tend not to use it unless there's absolutely no other choice.

Comment: Oh! I should have included my python version is 2.6 hence I can not use lxml. My mistake!

Comment: Find all returns list and list object throws a does not have attribute text

Comment: @python6 `findall()` does indeed return a list, and a list  indeeddoesn't have a text attribute, but `list()[0]` does have that attribute. I just tried it again and it works. So I'm not sure what the problem is on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<xml>
<document>
<fit>
<grp> some tags </grp>
<prp> 
<p> <id> 1674 </id> </p>
<drp> 
<name> Joe </name>
<post> 
<company> abc </company>
<company> Ltd. </company>
</post>
</drp>
</prp>
</fit>
</document>
<document>
.
.
.
</xml>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = []
rows.append(['ID', 'NAME', 'NCOMP'])
for document in doc.documents:
  rows.append([document.id.text,document.name.text," ".join(document.companys.text)])
utils.save2csv('test.csv',rows)
```

Result:

```
ID,NAME,NCOMP
1674,Joe,abc Ltd.
```